# Execute batch file when .log file contains text

Tags: windows, powershell, batch

I've done a lot of searching around and trial and error. I thought this would be a simple task, but I'm not having any luck...

I have a .log file (call it output.log) that automatically gets updated by a program. Each time a certain text appears (call it "test") in that file, I want a program or batch file to run. I also want it to stay open and run the program each recurring time the text appears.

I'm using Windows 10.

I've tried this:

```
powershell -command "select-string -path c:\output.log -pattern "text" | "c:\Windows\System32\calc.exe"
```

But it runs the calc regardless of whether there's a match for "text" in the file or not...

Comment: Take a l ook at [Watch file for changes and run command with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066742/watch-file-for-changes-and-run-command-with-powershell). You want to implement a [FileSystemWatcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0) to monitor your `.log` file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bat
@echo off 

setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd/d "%~dp0" & set "_cnt=0"

:loop
for /f %%i in ('type output.log^|find/c /i "text"
')do if "%%~i" == "!_cnt!" (goto :loop) else set "_cnt=%%~i"

start "" /b "%__AppDir__%calc.exe" & cls 
%__AppDir__%timeout.exe 3 | echo\Waiting for file change ...

goto :loop
```

---

> *But I'm looking to keep it continuously monitoring, and execute the program with each subsequent addition of "text" to the .log file.**

You can count the occurrences of your string, and monitor the file ...
When you increase your hit counter, the program will be executed, otherwise, it waits...

---

> *Is there a way to "timeout" the loop? Let's say it gets to inputs within a minute of each other. I only want it to act on the first, and ignore the rest, but continue to monitor after that first minute.*

> I'm not sure I understand, my English is weak/poor, sorry! And, the closest to what I achieved may suggest:

> ```bat
> @echo off
>
> cd/d "%~dp0" && setlocal
> %__AppDir__%mode.com 82,3
> set "_MMSS=OS Get localdatetime"
> set "_wmic=%__AppDir__%wbem\wmic.exe"
>
> for /f useback %%i in (`type output.log^|find/c /i "text"`
>    )do set "_cnt=%%~i" && set "_start=%time: =0%"
>
> :loop
> for /f useback^delims^=. %%i in (`%_wmic% %_MMSS%^|%__AppDir__%findstr.exe \.`
>    )do set "_ms=%%~i" && set "_time=%_start:~0,8%/%time: =0%" & title <nul 
>
> set "_time=%_time:~0,17%" && if "%_60s%" == "" set /a "_60s=1%_ms:~-4%-9940"
>
> set "_msg=..\%~0 ^| %_time:/= / % ^| %_ms:~-4% ^>^= %_60s% ^| "
> title %_ms:~-4% ^| Occurrences: %_cnt% & echo;%_msg% %_cnt% && set "_ms=%_ms:~-4%"
>
> for /f useback %%i in (`type output.log^|find/c /i "text"`)do set "_cnt=%%i" && (
>    if %%~i gtr %_cnt% if %_ms% leq %_60s% start "" /b "%__AppDir__%calc.exe")
>   
> %__AppDir__%timeout.exe 5|echo...\Waiting for file change... & goto :loop
> ```

Comment: It works. But I'm looking to keep it continuously monitoring, and execute the program with each subsequent addition of "text" to the .log file. Does that make sense?

Comment: Take a l ook at [Watch file for changes and run command with powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29066742/watch-file-for-changes-and-run-command-with-powershell). You want to implement a [FileSystemWatcher](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesystemwatcher?view=net-5.0) to monitor your `.log` file.

Comment: @KeithMiller good one, ha!

Comment: @KeithMiller As I understand it, that method only monitors files for changes, creations, etc., not for specific text being added to the .log file?

Comment: Right. It's a building block. Every time you're alerted to a change, *YOUR* code reads the file to see what was added, then acts (or does nothing) accordingly. Someting like: `If (Get-Content Output.log)[-1] -match 'Test' { Do something} `. Of course, the real code will be slightly more complicated :D

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe ... The problem with the batch being the continual loop is if the process hangs or gets killed, etc. then the automation is hosed. I'd incorporate a file via a "counter" value and have task scheduler execute it every x seconds over relying on the batch to continually run once executed. That'd make it more reliable and resilient. Each time the counter is greater than the value in the counter file,  then execute logic, overwrite counter file value with the new GTR value, etc. It's been a while, but I recall I've done similar things with batch before like that for reliability reasons.

Comment: @ITThugNinja I understand, but I am waiting for the author to comment on my suggestion and comment.
Thanks for commenting, I don't know if my English would help with such clarity, thanks ...

Comment: It would be the case to use a status check from time to time, or through a "resettable" counter

Comment: I like the `%__AppDir__%` undocumented variable there!

Comment: @ItWasn'tMe This worked perfectly! Thank you! I do have one other question... Is there a way to "timeout" the loop? Let's say it gets to inputs within a minute of each other. I only want it to act on the first, and ignore the rest, but continue to monitor after that first minute.